# What's the purpose of $this->get('Item') in Joomla view.html.php example file?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, component, joomla-api, mvc

I refer to the code below, presented in [**Developing a MVC Component - Front End Function Example**:](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Example_of_a_frontend_update_function)

```
class HelloWorldViewUpdHelloWorld extends JView
{
    // Overwriting JView display method
    function display($tpl = null) 
    {
            $app            = JFactory::getApplication();
            $params         = $app->getParams();
            $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();

            // Get some data from the models
            $state          = $this->get('State');
            $item           = $this->get('Item');  //WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF THIS STATEMENT?
            $this->form     = $this->get('Form');

            // Check for errors.
            if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
            {
                    JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                    return false;
            }
            // Display the view
            parent::display($tpl);
    }
```

}

I don't understand the purpose of this statement and I also notice that **`$item`** does not appear in the code in file **`site/views/updhelloworld/tmpl/default.php`** on that webpage.

I actually have the same question for the **`view.html.php`** file of **`com_users/views/registration`** of **Joomla 3** code ( I thought by comparing the two form submit examples I could answer my question):

```
    $this->data     = $this->get('Data'); //WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF THIS STATEMENT? WHAT PRECISELY KIND OF DATA iS MEANT HERE?
    $this->form     = $this->get('Form');
    $this->state    = $this->get('State');
    $this->params   = $this->state->get('params');
```

And also here **`$this->data`** does not appear in the related **`tmpl/default.php`** file (?)

Comment: The really simple answer is that  you need the old values when you update unless you always want to wipe them out when the user goes to edit.    JForm takes care of a lot of the work of managing rendering the old  values for you so you won't see direct references.

Answer (score 5):

In classes extending `JView` or `JViewLegacy`, a call to `$this->get()` will call a function in registered model classes starting with get.  So calling `$this->get('Item')` will call a model's getItem method.

Comment: Is this still the advised best practice? I remember somewhere, in some thread that JView::get was going to be/ might be depreciated in the undetermined future.

Comment: In the JView(Legacy) API, this is the recommended practice.

Answer (score 3):

The **`$this->get('Item')`** calls the function **`getItem()`** in the model, and subsequently it loads the data from the database.

**`$this->get('Data')`** calls a method in the model that gets the registration form data and prepares it for use.

Have a look at **`getData`** in **`com_users/models/registration.php`**